# How does it compile? How can the compiler find the declaration of NSFetchedResultsController, when there is no obvious import statemetn?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I make my first steps in objective-c and cocoa. I typed in the following example class, which compiles well in the iPhone main project. When I use the sample class in an OCUnitTest, the compiler raise an error.

class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ProjekteTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;    
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end
```

Now the question: I see in UIKit.h no direct or indirect #import for the NSFetchedResultsController.h file.

**How does the compiler resolve this identifier (NSFetchedResultsController) ?**

I expected the compiler error not only in the UnitTest project, but also in the main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you've got a prefix header that's including CoreData.

Comment: I would like to point out there are no issues with your answer :)

Comment: Yes, I found it a minute later. I have added the missing #import statements in the .pch file and all works fine. Thank you for your help!